# Why blinks when the paypal button is rendered in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, paypal, next.js, paypal-buttons

I used react-paypal-button-v2 to display the paypal button as below.

When the window refreshes, only the button flashes.

I think it's because of animation rather than ssr.

Can I disable the default animation on the button?

```
npx create-next-app

pages/index.js


import { PayPalButton } from "react-paypal-button-v2";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <h1 className={styles.title}>
        Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
      </h1>
      <PayPalButton
        amount="0.01"
        onSuccess={() => {}}
        style={{ layout: `horizontal` }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

+++ 06/28

I tried to solve it using the state, but the problem still exists. ㅠㅠ

```
export default function Home() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      {isReady === "true" && (
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>
      )}
      <PayPalButton
        amount="0.01"
        onButtonReady={() => setIsReady("true")}
        onSuccess={() => {}}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is because of animation either. I can see a prop `onButtonReady` in docs whose description suggests that the component is first loading the paypal API. That fetch operation is probably what causing the flicker for you. You can try passing a callback like this `onButtonReady={() => console.log('loaded')}` and see if the info is logged at the same time the button appears. If that's the case I would recommend setting a state inside the callback and display the whole component once the button has loaded.

Comment: i still have problum ㅠㅠ